# Inputstream from WAP server, parse parts

Tags: image, mms

I have asked this question countless times on various forums. Ultimately all I need is a recommendation for a book or website. Hopefully an API can be recommended. I can code anything I just dont know where to look. I have Googled to the end of the web. Looked over several Java packages including the wireless toolkit. Ive seen python APIs to parse mms messages.

I am using Java. I currently have various algorithms to attach an inputstream to an mms message on a WAP server.

The message on the server is an SMIL message? XML? I would parse the inputstream into XML? Then I could go through the nodes of the xml looking for an image part?

Can I just parse the raw inputstream looking for an image?

Where do I begin? Maybe someone can reply with a consolidating paragraph of how to read a raw mms inputstream and parse the contents into discrete objects which can then be subsequently processed. I know how to process the image and anything else the part may contain, I just need to know how to get to the image. Ultimately I just want to attach an inputstream only on the image and then I'm good to go.

What book will teach me where to begin? What APIs can be recommended?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend *Multimedia Messaging Service: An Engineering Approach to MMS* by Gwenaël Le Bodic ([http://www.amazon.com/Multimedia-Messaging-Service-Engineering-Approach/dp/047086253X/ref=ntt_at_ep_dpi_2](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/047086253X)) to get a decent understanding of MMS, and then check out the OMA specifications for more detail.

You might also find http://www.mbuni.org/ helpful, although it's not written in Java.

Comment: Thank you very much. Im working with Java on Android. The phone handles incoming MMS fine and simply adds the parts to a sql table, which is easily accessible. Sending an MMS has no api in the sdk and I'm going to have to do it the hard way ;)

Comment: @Noah no worries; I've added a link to an open source MMS library that might help you.